# Getting an error message when I instantiate my ArrayAdapter subclass

Tags: java, android

I'm following an online tutorial about creating a ListView and populating it with custom data using an ArrayAdapter subclass. A ListView item basically contains 2 TextViews and an ImageView.

Here's a snippet of my custom ArrayAdapter subclass, along with its constructor code:

```
public class WordAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Word> {

    private static final String LOG_TAG = WordAdapter.class.getSimpleName();

    public WordAdapter(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull ArrayList<Word> objects) {
        super(context, 0, objects);
    }

....other overriden methods here...

}
```

Then I instantiate the WordAdapter in my Activity like this:

```
package com.example.android.miwok;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.ListView;
import java.util.ArrayList;

    public class NumbersActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.word_list);

        ArrayList<Word> words = new ArrayList<>();
        words.add(new Word("...", "...", R.drawable.number_one));
        words.add(new Word("...", "...", R.drawable.number_two));

        WordAdapter wordAdapter = new WordAdapter(this, words);
        ListView listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
        listView.setAdapter(wordAdapter);
    }
}
```

Now I'm getting this error message on the line where I instantiate my WordAdapter. It says:
[image]

Strangely enough, even with this error message, I'm able to compile and run the app successfully on my emulators. Everything is working as expected. But I would still like to know how I can resolve this error message as it might cause me trouble down the line.

Using Android Studio 3.1.2 by the way.

Comment: Add full code where are you having `WordAdapter wordAdapter = new WordAdapter(this, words);`.

Comment: Updated my post with full code from my Activity class. That line is basically inside onCreate()

Comment: Seems Ok to me . Try to check import of `Word` in both classes .

Comment: In `new WordAdapter(this, words);` 
try replacing `this` by `getApplicationContext()` (or `getContext()`)

Comment: @ADM The Word file/class is in the same package so the import doesn't matter right?  The autocomplete can fully detect the properties/methods of the Word class within the Activity class so I think  import is not the problem. Also, in my settings, I have `Add unambiguous imports on the fly`.

Comment: @Nofix I tried `getApplicationContext()` and `getContext()` but the compiler can't seem to resolve those methods.

Comment: @aresz If you can make it run on your emulator but you keep getting the error, I would suggest clean and rebuild project (Build -> Clean)

Comment: @Nofix So I tried cleaning and rebuilding the project but the error message remains :(

Comment: @aresz maybe try to cast `this` as `Context` ? :')

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170095/discussion-between-nofix-and-aresz).

Comment: This is not `Context` issue . Cause `Activity` is child of `Context` . If you calling this directly inside `onCreate()` then it should accept the Context with `this`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out the problem. The tutorial I'm following had a starting template project. When I opened it with the latest Android Studio and SDK version, AS prompted to me update the versions in the project's build.gradle. So I went ahead and updated as suggested. That seemed to messed some things up and caused the error message I was talking about in my original post.

I just redownloaded the template project, this time not updating the versions inside the build.gradle and that made the error message go away. I guess we can't always rely on build.gradle update suggestions :)